# VBA adding to an existing CSV file

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to make some VBA that will add data to an existing CSV file, I have the below code but it overwrites the existing data instead of adding to it. I am guessing as it goes to the beginning of the file but am unsure how to force to add to the file.

```
Sub WriteCSV()
    Dim iLastRow As Long
    Dim iLastCol As Long
    Dim FilePath As String
    Dim Filename As String
    Dim Fullpath As String
    
    Fullpath = Worksheets("GUI").Range("f11")
    iLastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    iLastCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        Open Fullpath For Append As #1
            For i = 1 To iLastRow
               For j = 1 To iLastCol
                    If j <> iLastCol Then 'keep writing to same line
                        Write #1, Cells(i, j),
                    Else 'end the line
                        Write #1, Cells(i, j)
                    End If
                Next j
            Next i
           
        Close #1
       
    End Sub
```

Comment: Your code works as is for me and appends the data to the existing file.

Comment: You probably intended to use WriteLine at 'end of line.

Answer (score 1):

Excel works well well with CSV files as workbooks.  This approach may solve your problem.  Although, writing to the filesystem with VBA will be faster.

```
Sub writeCSV()
    Dim csv As Workbook
    Dim data_sheet As Worksheet
    
    Set data_sheet = ActiveSheet
    
    Set csv = Workbooks.Open(Worksheets("GUI").Range("f11").Value)
    data_sheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy csv.Worksheets(1).Cells(csv.Worksheets(1).Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    
    csv.Close True

End Sub
```